# How can I use pagination in this case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari

I'm using the gem called **'acts_as_follower'** and **'kaminari'**.
If I put `.page(params[:page]).per(10)` in the end of the line that fetches records with `acts_as_follower`, it gives back error. So I removed it.
How can I use pagination with this gem **'acts_as_follower'**?

**Error**

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#following
undefined method `page' for #<Array:0x00000018593928>

Extracted source (around line #53):

50: <% end %>
51: 
52: <div class='pagination'>
53:     <%= page_entries_info(@users).html_safe %>
54:     <%= paginate @users, :window => 4, :outer_window => 5, :left => 2, :right => 2 %>
55: </div>
56:
```

current **users_controller.rb** Fetching part

```
@users = User.find_by_username(params[:id]).all_following(order: 'updated_at DESC')
```

Comment: Anyone  can help me with this please?

Comment: <%= page_entries_info(@users).html_safe %> remove this line

Comment: @vijikumar Thanks I know. but I have to use it with pagination

Comment: https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#orm--template-engine-agnostic please look into this

Comment: @vijikumar Yes, I looked at it. But it doesn't talk about any in this case

Comment: the same below answer is there in the above link. read carefully :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `all_following(order: 'updated_at DESC')` method returns an array object, you'd need to use Kaminari's `PaginatableArray`.

Add the code below to your controller:

```
@users = Kaminari.paginate_array(@users).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Then the pagination should work as you'd expect.